# Getting to know the using of Git with Flutter

Tags: flutter, github

I'm a beginner in Flutter, and I don't know if it is right to clone a project in Android Studio that has been from 2 years ago, I got an error involving the difference of the Flutter versions that opens the cloned project and the framework in my device, I know how to use git and how to use the widgets and the APIs of Flutter, but my problem is with projects cloning from GitHub.
My other concern is, how to reuse a specific UI from another project in GitHub for my project so I save time.
And finally, I don’t know if a confliction happens when I clone a project from an old version of Flutter, and is it okay to combine codes from GitHub to my project to save time and trouble.

I cloned a project and got an error concerning the version of the cloned project, but the framework and the IDE in my device are fine, and the app worked on the emulator but I have a little concern.

Answer (score 0):

- of course you can clone projects from GitHub even if they were outdated, the problem is flutter is regulary updated and sometimes you'd find a remarkable changes in the previous versions, so if you can find a newer one with the same topic it's always safer and better.
  also, if you're new to flutter I wouldn't recommend using the exact same code for the ui widgets, unless you're 100% that you're  able to do them in your own first, otherwise you'll find a big difficulties when you create your own widgets after that.